# Solve System of Linear Equations in MatLab with Matrix of Arbitrary Size for Finite Difference Calculation

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I am trying to write a script in MatLab R2016a that can solve a system of linear equations that can have different sizes depending on the values of `p` and `Q`.

I have the following equations that I am trying to solve, where `h=[-p:1:p]*dx`. Obviously, there is some index `m` where `h=0`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

[image: First Equation]

[image: Other Equations]

[image: Matrix]

I'm trying to write a function where I can input `p` and `Q` and build the matrix and then just solve it to get the coefficients. Is there a way to build a matrix using the variables `p`, `Q`, and `h` instead of using different integer values for each individual case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [bsxfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)(in recent matlab versions this function may be implented to the interpreter, I don't know for sure):

```
p = 4;
Q = 8;
dx = 1;

h = -p:p*dx

Qvector = [Q,1:Q-1]'

Matrix = bsxfun(@(Qvector, h)h.^(Qvector)./factorial(Qvector), Qvector, h)
```

Output:

```
h =

-4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4


Qvector =

 8
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7

Matrix =

    1.6254    0.1627    0.0063    0.0000         0    0.0000    0.0063    0.1627    1.6254
   -4.0000   -3.0000   -2.0000   -1.0000         0    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000
    8.0000    4.5000    2.0000    0.5000         0    0.5000    2.0000    4.5000    8.0000
  -10.6667   -4.5000   -1.3333   -0.1667         0    0.1667    1.3333    4.5000   10.6667
   10.6667    3.3750    0.6667    0.0417         0    0.0417    0.6667    3.3750   10.6667
   -8.5333   -2.0250   -0.2667   -0.0083         0    0.0083    0.2667    2.0250    8.5333
    5.6889    1.0125    0.0889    0.0014         0    0.0014    0.0889    1.0125    5.6889
   -3.2508   -0.4339   -0.0254   -0.0002         0    0.0002    0.0254    0.4339    3.2508
```